# Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with array literal

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to upgrade to upgrade my project to Swift 2 but I stuck on the following error:

> Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with array literal

Here's my code:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.08)
    let file = PFFile(data: data!)

    PFUser.currentUser()!["Picture"] = [file]
    try! PFUser.currentUser()!.save()}
```

And here’s the line where the problem occur

```
        PFUser.currentUser()!["Picture"] = [file]
```

Thanks a lot for your help !! (I'm beginner,...)

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: It works but I have now an another problem I now get the following error:invalid type for key Picture, expected array, but got file

Comment: while the code worked perfectly previously (and thanks a lot for your help)

Comment: I would have to see more of your code to figure out what the other problem you are facing now is.

Comment: ok thanks a lot I've solved by problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

substitute this line:

```
PFUser.currentUser()!["Picture"] = [file]
```

with:

```
PFUser.currentUser()!["Picture"] = file
```

**Edit:** As noted, it is better practice to not force unwrap a conditional and do something as follows:

```
guard let user = PFUser.currentUser() else {
    return
}
user["Picture"] = file
```

Comment: It is better to not encourage force unwrap of optionals. We should `guard let user = PFUser.currentUser() else { return }` and then `user["Picture"] = file`